# How to create pdf of html webpage using php predefined function pdf

Tags: php, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

i have a user defined function which return me html content . so i just wanna print this html in PDF file and downloaded directly as PDF

thanks in advance....

Comment: Have a look at: http://www.fpdf.org/

Comment: i dont want to use 3rd party application..it is possible using php pdf function (http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdf.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HTML 2 FPDF script did it for me. http://sourceforge.net/projects/html2fpdf/

```
// If html2pdf folder placed in root directory
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/html2pdf/html2fpdf.php');

// Create new HTML2PDF class for an A4 page, measurements in mm
$pdf = new HTML2FPDF('P','mm','A4');

// Optional top margin
$pdf->SetTopMargin(1);
$pdf->AddPage();
// Control the x-y position of the html
$pdf->SetXY(0,0);
$pdf->WriteHTML($html);

// The 'D' arg forces the browser to download the file 
$pdf->Output('MyFile.pdf','D');
```

Note that some elements may render incorrectly (images for me), in which case you have to write those elements directly. See the [fpdf manual](http://www.fpdf.org/).

Comment: i am facing problem with output option 'D'  
$pdf->Output('MyFile.pdf','D');  
when i opened file its show me error file has been damaged..

Comment: @LuckyW Try placing `ob_end_clear();` at the start and `die;` at the end. Any other HTML that you output may corrupt the file.

Comment: @MarcelWasko I am getting a blank PDF. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    include("MPDF56/mpdf.php");

    $mpdf=new mPDF('c','A4','','',32,25,27,25,16,13); 
    $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
    $mpdf->showImageErrors = true;

    $mpdf->list_indent_first_level = 0; // 1 or 0 - whether to indent the first level of a list    

    $html='<html><head></head><body>Test</body></html>'; //Assign HTML HERE    
    $cssPath        = base_url('assets/css/voucher.css'); //any CSS File you want to Include


    $stylesheet     =   file_get_contents($cssPath);   

    $mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);    // The parameter 1 tells that this is css/style only and no body/html/text

    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html,2);



    if ( $action  ==   'view') 
    {        
        $mpdf->Output('mpdf.pdf','I');           
    }
    else
    {   

        $file_path  =   FTP_PATH."testfile".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$filename.".pdf";    //FTP_PATH = Location where you want to right PDF
        $mpdf->Output( $file_path,'F');      
        file_put_contents(FTP_PATH.'testfile\\'.$filename.'.pdf', $output);                 
    }

?>
```

Download Library from here http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php

Comment: Thanks nana chorage for Answer.....

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use this software: PDFCrowd or install a plugin from them to your Chrome or FF browser.

Alternativly, you can also check this out :)

- [Htmldoc](http://www.msweet.org/projects.php?Z1): please note this is in 2001 in Htmldoc

and this (however its not free) [PrinceXML](http://princexml.com/):

It's definitely the best HTML/CSS to PDF converter out there, although it's not free (But hey, your programming is not free either, so if it saves you 10 hours of work, you're home free.)

Oh yeah, did I mention that this is the first (and probably only) HTML2PDF solution that does full ACID2!?